# Bascis of NancyFx Bootstrapper

Tags: nancy, bootstrapper

I am a beginner in Nancy application develpment.
Can any one explain about what is the  role of Bootstrapper in a Nancy application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [Nancy documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapper) explains it well.

the bootstrapper is for application wide configuration. That includes setting up your DI container, adding hanlders to `Before`, `After` and `Error` pipelines, setting up any special conventions you may have and so on. The modules are discovered automatically by Nancy on startup. If you don't have any particular setup, you don't need a bootstrapper.

Comment: thanks for the link, it sounds like, its role is to linking the modules for execution,  Can you explain in your words if am missing any thing please.